# Highlight style in TimePicker control of Telerik

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I am using their TimePicker control in Silverlight and the issue is if I automatically populate the time and click on the clock icon, it does not auto-highlight the time for me in the drop down but if I use the drop down to pick the time, then yes it is highlighted.

[image]

I looked at my XAML for the control and I found that I do have this:

```
x:Name="PART_DropDownButton"
controls:DateTimePickerExtensions.FocusContentOnOpen="True"
```

but still no luck, also went and directly set that property on the specific XAML file in my application and still no luck.
Any thing else to try?

Comment: It should update when the new value is assigned, you're just doing like myTimePicker.SelectedTime=blah?

Comment: What property are you setting for populating time  ?

Comment: it does update and show it in the text area of the control. Problem is in the drop down it does not highlight it, notice in the screen shot 10:00 AM IS highlighted.

Comment: @grv_9098 I'm binding to "SelectedValue"